# Format results in table

Tags: powershell, format, output, tabular

My script below searches for a specific part number (459279) recursively through a number of txt files.

```
set-location C:\Users\admin\Desktop\PartNumbers\
$exclude = @('PartNumbers.txt','*.ps1')
$Line = [Environment]::NewLine
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Exclude $exclude | select-string 459279 | group count | Format-Table -Wrap -AutoSize -Property Count,
@{Expression={$_.Group | foreach { $_.filename} | Foreach {"$_$Line"} }; Name="Filename"},
@{Expression={$_.Group | foreach {$_.LineNumber} | Foreach {"$_$Line"} }; Name="LineNumbers"} | Out-File 459279Results.txt
```

My Results are:

```
Count Filename                           LineNumbers
----- --------                           -----------
    2 {Customer1.txt                     {2         
      , Customer2.txt                    , 3        
      }                                  }
```

My ideal results would be if this is possible:

```
Part Number: 459279
Count: 2

Filename                           LineNumbers
--------                           -----------
Customer1.txt                      2         
Customer2.txt                      3
```

I have manually retrieved the part number '459279' from "PartNumbers.txt" and searched for it using the script.

I cannot seem to remove/replace the braces and commas to present a clean list.

What I hope to eventually do is to recursively search through "PartNumbers.txt" and produce a report with each part number appended to the next in the style mentioned above.

PartNumbers.txt is formatted:

```
895725
939058
163485
459279
498573
```

Customer*.txt are formatted:

```
163485
459279
498573
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you provide an excerpt from **PartNumbers.txt** so we can see the format. It's hard to tell you how to exclude the commas and curly braces without knowing where they're coming from.

Comment: My apologies, I have now added the extra details. I wanted to point out that in the example I gave that I manually got the part number from the text file and copied it to the script. I have not made it as far as looping through the **PartNumbers.txt**. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
$exclude = 'PartNumbers.txt', '*.ps1'
$root    = 'C:\Users\admin\Desktop\PartNumbers'
$outfile = Join-Path $root 'loopResults.txt'

Get-Content (Join-Path $root 'PartNumbers.txt') | % {
  $partno = $_
  $found = Get-ChildItem $root -Recurse -Exclude $exclude `
             | ? { -not $_.PSIsContainer } `
             | Select-String $partno `
             | % {
               $a = $_ -split ':'
               New-Object -Type PSCustomObject -Property @{
                 'Filename'    = Split-Path -Leaf $a[1];
                 'LineNumbers' = $a[2]
               }
             }

  "Part Number: $partno"
  'Count: ' + @($found).Count
  $found | Format-Table Filename, LineNumbers
} | Out-File $outfile -Append
```

Comment: This is perfect thank you. Any hints on how to loop through **PartNumbers.txt** and append each part numbers results after one another?

Comment: Simply add an outer loop that iterates over the content of that file. See updated answer.

Comment: Thank you, this is awesome. I find it interesting that if there is only 1 occurrence of a part number that the count result is empty. Not a problem though.

Comment: I am struggling with **| Out-File C:\Users\admin\Desktop\PartNumbers\loopResults.txt -append** which i have tried to add. I have placed it after **$found | Format-Table Filename, LineNumbers**. It produces the txt file but it does not display properly - should i be adding it elsewhere or perhaps its not possible to export?

Comment: You can't pipeline output from a `foreach ($item in $set)` loop. If you want to pipeline output you need to adjust the outer loop so that it works with pipelines. See updated answer.

Comment: One final thought - when 0 or 1 part number is found in the customer files, they return no result but simply say **Count: **. Is it possible to have a return of **Count: 0** and **Count: 1** respectively? I tried adding **+ '1'** to **'Count: ' + $found.Count** along with a few other scenarios but could not work out any placement that worked - my trials simply added a static numberal to the result i.e. instead of 10, which would be the correct count, the result was 101.

Comment: If zero or one elements are found, the result is not an array, thus not providing a `Count` property. Wrap the variable in `@()` to make it into an array. See updated answer.

Comment: **Count:0**  actually does not seem to work, it shows up as **Count: 1** also but without a **filename** or **linenumber** underneath.

Comment: Inspect the type of the variable: `if ($found -ne $null) {$found.GetType()}`. When no matches are found, `$found` should be `$null`.

Comment: I Ended up with `$testForZero = @(if ($found -ne $null) {@($found).Count} Else {'0'})` and further down `'Count: ' + $testForZero` - This gives me what I want. Thanks again.